# How to use Activiti diagram in java applications?

Tags: java, web-applications, activiti

I am new to Java web application and am trying to design one. I was wondering how the Activiti diagram (.bpmn file) simplify the web application design in Java. For example, if I design a workflow for a simple HR application for new employee hiring in Activiti diagram, will it automatically generate relevant Java classes for me? In other words, how are Activiti diagrams related to the Java classes directly?

Answer (score 0):

If not mistaken, only service tasks can use java classes, but there is no automatic generation. You must write all classes by yourself and in Activiti diagram mark appropriate service tasks like this:

```
<serviceTask id="javaService"
             name="My Java Service Task"
             activiti:class="org.activiti.MyJavaDelegate" />
```

Full info you can find [here](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html).